# Minimizing/Maximizing youTube video in YouTubePlayerView

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have a container where I show a GIF video.On click of the GIF it opens the same video in YouTube. YouTubePlayerView has maximize and minimize icon, when I click on that video is just restarting instead of minimizing it and get back to the same container. I am not sure how to minimize the video which is playing in YouTubePlayerView.

I have created a separate Activity called YouTubeACtivity:

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String shortCode = "";

    public static void show(Activity activity, String shortCode)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, YoutubeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.YOUTUBE_VIDEO, shortCode);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtubeplayer);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        shortCode = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.YOUTUBE_VIDEO);


            YouTubePlayerFragment mYoutubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerFragment().newInstance();

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.youtubeContainer, mYoutubePlayerFragment);
            ft.commit();

            if (mYoutubePlayerFragment != null) {
                mYoutubePlayerFragment.initialize(getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean restored) {
                        //youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                        youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE| YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);
                       // youTubePlayer.  setShowFullscreenButton(false);

                        youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) {

                              //  onBackPressed();

                            }
                        });


                        Log.e("shortcode ", "reached" + shortCode);
                        if (shortCode != null) {

                            if (restored) {
                                youTubePlayer.play();
                            } else {
                                youTubePlayer.loadVideo("" + shortCode + "");
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                        Log.e("youtube initialization ", "initialisation fails");
                    }
                });
            }

    }


}
```

The GIF video is showing in a FrameLayout which implements SurfaceHolder callback.

I just wanted to know is there anyway we can make minimize the video and comeback to the container layout.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest to use the player object to go or exit  fullscreen

```
youtubeplayer.setFullScreen(true/false);
```

then add config changes in manifest of the activity containing the container

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|screenLayout"
```

as far as i can understand your problem your activity is getting restarted

Comment: if this doesn't help tell me

Comment: what's the exact problem, is video restarting when you click on minimize icon or it restarts when you click on the same video